# server-side datatables in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, pagination, datatables

I am using server-side processing with DataTables in my Rails 4 app. I have my ajax source returning accurate data records from DB. Paginatation works on the html side, i.e. page 1 showing 1-10 of 800 entries, page 2 showing 11-20 of 800 entries, and so on. However, the actual records in the table are the same 10 results. I don't know if it is just redrawing the table with the same 10 records for each page because I've missed something or what.

Does anyone know why I return the same 10 records for every page? Any insight is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Gemfile:

```
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', github: 'rweng/jquery-datatables-rails'
```

Controller:

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: HomeownersDatatable.new(view_context) }
  end
end
```

HomeownersDatatable:

```
class HomeownersDatatable
delegate :params, :link_to, to: :@view

def initialize(view)
    @view = view
end

def as_json(options = {})
    {
        sEcho: params[:sEcho].to_i,
        iTotalRecords: Homeowner.count,
        iTotalDisplayRecords: homeowners.total_entries,
        aaData: data,
    }
end

private
def data
    homeowners.map do |homeowner|
        [
            link_to(homeowner.name, @view.edit_admin_homeowner_path(homeowner.id)),
            # (homeowner.name),
            (homeowner.id),
            (homeowner.email),
            (homeowner.address),
            (homeowner.zip_code),
        ]
    end
end

def homeowners
    @homeowners ||= fetch_homeowners
end

def fetch_homeowners
    homeowners = Homeowner.order("#{sort_column} " "#{sort_direction}")
    homeowners = homeowners.page(page).per_page(per_page)
    if params[:sSearch].present?
        homeowners = homeowners.where("name like :search or email like :search", search: "%#{params[:sSearch]}%")
    end
    homeowners
end

def page
    params[:iDisplayStart].to_i/per_page + 1
end

def per_page
    params[:iDisplayLength].to_i > 0 ? params[:iDisplayLength].to_i : 20
end

def sort_column
    columns = %w[id email]
    columns[params[:iSortCol_0].to_i]
end

def sort_direction
    params[:sSortDir_0] == "DESC" ? "DESC" : "ASC"
end
```

end

JS to Initailize table:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#homeowners_admin_table').DataTable({
    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
    "stateSave": true,
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": $('#homeowners_admin_table').data('source'),
  });
});
```

Comment: Is the `iDisplayStart` value being set correctly during paging?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I figured it out by changing:

```
$('#table').DataTable({{...})
```

for:

```
$('#table').dataTable({{...}).
```

It is just about the datatable version.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line of code:

```
"ajax": $('#homeowners_admin_table').data('source')
```

To:

```
sAjaxSource: $('#homeowners_admin_table').data('source')
```